# Plotly chart area cuts off text

Tags: charts, plotly

I have the following plotly code:

```
            var element = document.getElementById(scope.changeid);

        function getData(division,redraw) {
            var employeeData = [];
            if (!division) {
                $http.get(api.getUrl('competenceUserAverageByMyDivisions', null)).success(function (response) {
                    processData(response,redraw);
                });
            }
            else {
                $http.get(api.getUrl('competenceUserAverageByDivision', division)).success(function (response) {
                    processData(response,redraw);
                })
            }

        }

        function processData(data,redraw) {
            var y = [],
                x1 = [],
                x2 = [];

            data.forEach(function (item) {
                y.push(item.user.profile.firstname);
                x1.push(item.current_level);
                x2.push(item.expected);
            });

            var charData = [{
                    x: y,
                    y: x1,
                    type: 'bar',

                    name: $filter('translate')('COMPETENCES.GRAPH.CURRENT'),
                    marker: {
                        color: '#23b7e5'
                    }
                }, {
                    x:y,
                    y:x2,
                    type: 'bar',
                    marker: {
                        color: '#f05050'
                    },
                    name: $filter('translate')('COMPETENCES.GRAPH.EXPECTED')
                }],
                layout = {
                    title: $filter('translate')('USERMANAGEMENT.USERS'),
                    barmode: 'stack',
                    legend: {
                        traceorder: 'reversed'

                    }
                };

            Plotly.newPlot(element,charData,layout);
        }

        scope.$watch('divisionId', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue) {
                getData(newValue.id,true);
            }
        }, true);

        getData(null,false);
```

This generates the following chart:

```
                            <div class="panel-body">
                            <h4 class="text-center">{{'COMPETENCES.GRAPH_TITLES.OVERVIEW_GAP' | translate}}</h4>
                            <vertical-bar-chart id="chartArea" goto="competence.titleCompetenceDetails"
                                                changeid="chartArea" xcolumn="xColumn" y-column="yColumn"
                                                dataset="dataSet"
                                                has-addition="true"
                                                style="width: 80%; text-align: center"></vertical-bar-chart>
                        </div>
```

[image]

As you might be able to tell the text (x column) is being unintentionally cut off. So my question is how can i avoid this? i have attempted to increase the height of the element however without any luck :(

AS you can see here:

[image]

(oh you cant tell because of the white background but the height of panel body is 1000 px however it still cuts it off.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try increasing the bottom margin in layout.margin.b (more info in the plotlyjs [reference page](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-margin).

Answer (score 1):

For reference, I had the same issue, margin bottom didn't help, but after the graph was created, I ran the following JQuery which revealed the hidden text:

```
var heightincrease = $('#yourID').find('.svg-container').height() + 100;
$('#yourID').find('.svg-container').height(heightincrease).find('.main-svg').height(heightincrease);
```

Obviously adjust as required to reveal your whole graph.  Will probably break resizing so will need work if that's a concern.